# create a timer job to run once a month which exports sharepoint list items to excel and stores in a document library

Tags: c#, excel, sharepoint, timer, sharepoint-2010

I want to create a timer job or workflow which runs once a month and exports sharepoint list data to excel and stores this file in a document library.

I have downloaded the code to create timer job from below link but dont know how to include the above requirement
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SharePoint-2010-Custom-416cd3a1

```
//Create class derived from SPJonDefinition Class 
 class ListTimerJob : SPJobDefinition 
    { 
         public ListTimerJob() 

            : base() 
        { 

        } 

        public ListTimerJob(string jobName, SPService service, SPServer server, SPJobLockType targetType) 

            : base(jobName, service, server, targetType) 
        { 

        } 

        public ListTimerJob(string jobName, SPWebApplication webApplication) 

            : base(jobName, webApplication, null, SPJobLockType.ContentDatabase) 
        { 

            this.Title = "List Timer Job"; 

        } 

        public override void Execute(Guid contentDbId) 
        { 

            // get a reference to the current site collection's content database 

            SPWebApplication webApplication = this.Parent as SPWebApplication; 

            SPContentDatabase contentDb = webApplication.ContentDatabases[contentDbId]; 

            // get a reference to the "ListTimerJob" list in the RootWeb of the first site collection in the content database 

            SPList Listjob = contentDb.Sites[0].RootWeb.Lists["ListTimerJob"]; 

            // create a new list Item, set the Title to the current day/time, and update the item 

            SPListItem newList = Listjob.Items.Add(); 

            newList["Title"] = DateTime.Now.ToString(); 

            newList.Update(); 

        } 
} 
//Add Event receiver at Feature Level  
[Guid("9a724fdb-e423-4232-9626-0cffc53fb74b")] 
public class Feature1EventReceiver : SPFeatureReceiver 
    { 
        const string List_JOB_NAME = "ListLogger"; 
        // Uncomment the method below to handle the event raised after a feature has been activated. 

        public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties) 
        { 
            SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite; 

            // make sure the job isn't already registered 

            foreach (SPJobDefinition job in site.WebApplication.JobDefinitions) 
            { 

                if (job.Name == List_JOB_NAME) 

                    job.Delete(); 

            } 

            // install the job 

            ListTimerJob listLoggerJob = new ListTimerJob(List_JOB_NAME, site.WebApplication); 

            SPMinuteSchedule schedule = new SPMinuteSchedule(); 

            schedule.BeginSecond = 0; 

            schedule.EndSecond = 59; 

            schedule.Interval = 5; 

            listLoggerJob.Schedule = schedule; 

            listLoggerJob.Update(); 

        } 

        // Uncomment the method below to handle the event raised before a feature is deactivated. 

        public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties) 
        { 
            SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite; 

            // delete the job 

            foreach (SPJobDefinition job in site.WebApplication.JobDefinitions) 
            { 

                if (job.Name == List_JOB_NAME) 

                    job.Delete(); 

            } 

}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify "how to include the above requirement"? Right now your post only contains requirements and there is no problem to solve on SO. Side note: please make sure to include only minimum amount of code directly related to your problem in your posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the SPMinuteSchedule  to SPMonthlyByDaySchedule, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spschedule.aspx.

But, my recommendation is to use windows server scheduler and console application. Easy to change, easy to maintain (not iisreset!!) , and easy to log everything. We use console applications for various scheduled jobs, varying from 1 hour to 1 day.

Comment: Can you give me the link for any samples in console application scheduler for sharepoint?

Comment: For how to make a schedculer http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993.aspx, for console application+scom https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zO8DIs_IKEI

Answer (score 1):

I would also advice you not to use `SharePoint` timer jobs engine. 
It's definitely not stable.
Sometimes jobs simply don't `trigger`, they are difficult and slow to instantiate.

Of course you could always spend time tweaking `SharePoint` to achieve stability, but there is no guarantee.  I know it sounds imperative, but trust me, I can't remember all the problems we had with this engine, but we lost much time on it.

I recommend you **Quartz.NET** or **Windows Scheduler**, as mentionned earlier.
These are well proven solutions, used by many people, also for SharePoint.

We implemented Quartz.Net for SharePoint at my company, all our Timer Jobs run on this engine.
We had no glitch for two years.

Best Regards.